# Upgrade Mongo DB 2.4.1 to 2.4.6

Tags: mongodb

Currently, I am using MongoDB 2.4.1 in my all shard clusters. I need to upgrade to MongoDB 2.4.6.

Please help me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the release notes? It gives steps in there

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am reading that, but, Is there any easy way to upgrade?

Comment: Unfortunately not, there is not sort of automated way really, you have to do it piece by piece, personally 2.6 is going to be out soon, I would wait to upgrade to that

Answer (score 1):

If you are upgrading between point releases (for example, 2.4.x to 2.4.y), the upgrade process should just be updating the binaries. As a general rule there should be no changes in data file format, config metadata, or backward compatibility within the same major release series.

It's definitely worth reading the [release notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/) and [upgrade notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4-upgrade/) to be clear on the changes and any upgrade caveats. I would also encourage you to upgrade to the latest available production version in your release series (currently 2.4.9) as there are generally worthwhile performance and stability improvements.

#### Recommended steps for 2.4.x -> 2.4.y sharded cluster upgrade

The recommended steps for [upgrading sharded cluster components](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4-upgrade/#upgrade-sharded-cluster-components) with minimal disruption are:

1. [Disable the balancer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#disable-the-balancer) to avoid migration errors during the upgrade period.

   NOTE: *If a migration is currently in progress, it will be completed before the balancer is disabled.*
2. Upgrade all `mongos` instances in the cluster, in any order.
3. Upgrade all 3 `mongod` config server instances.

   NOTE: *You should ideally upgrade the first server listed in the `mongos --configdb`
   argument last (i.e. upgrade the config servers in the reverse of the order listed in your `--configdb` string).*
4. Upgrade each shard, one at a time.

   NOTE: *You should ideally upgrade the `mongod` secondaries first, and then run [`rs.stepDown()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.stepDown/) to elect a new primary before upgrading the primary of each shard. You may wish to run [`rs.freeze(60)`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.freeze/) on the current primary to ensure it is ineligible for re-election.*
5. [Enable the balancer](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#enable-the-balancer) once all upgrades are complete.